# Response from Azure AD B2C without Email?

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-ad-b2c

I have set up a new B2C Tenant in Azure and I'm using [oauth2_proxy](https://github.com/bitly/oauth2_proxy) (more specific: [docker-oauth2_proxy](https://github.com/machine-data/docker-oauth2_proxy)) to authenticate against it.

There was a need to configure custom login URLs, but the login process itself is working:

```
        - name: OAUTH2_PROXY_LOGIN_URL
          value: https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/<my-tenant-name>.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_policy/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
        - name: OAUTH2_PROXY_REDEEM_URL
          value: https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/<my-tenant-name>.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_policy/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

However, I get an error after I'm redirected back to https://my-app.example.com:

```
oauthproxy.go:527: error redeeming code missing email
```

I tried to have a look at the token that I get back, but could not decode it via https://jwt.ms.

As I don't know what exactly is contained in there, I am reluctant to post it here, but it does start with `eyJraWQi...`, which can be base-64-decoded to `{"kid":"cpimcore_09252015","ver":"1.0","zip":"Deflate","ser":"1.0"}`

The full format of the reply is:

```
/oauth2/callback?state=a0d367fd2d7337b8fbae8d72052022c7%3a%2f&code=eyJraWQiOiJjcGltY29yZV8wOTI1MjAxNSIsInZlciI6IjEuMCIsInppcCI6IkRlZmxhdGUiLCJzZXIiOiIxLjAifQ..[base64*16].[base64*568].[base64*22]
```

where `[base64*n]` indicates a string of `n` characters that look like base 64 encoded data.

Any ideas on how to decode that token?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't decode the authorization code that is issued to `/oauth2/callback` because it is encrypted.

[oauth2_proxy's Azure AD provider](https://github.com/bitly/oauth2_proxy/blob/a94b0a8b25e553f7333f7b84aeb89d9d18ec259b/providers/azure.go#L86) expects a **mail** or **otherMails** claim to be issued. Azure AD issues this but Azure AD B2C doesn't issue it. Azure AD B2C issues the **emails** claim.

You might have to modify this Azure AD provider to match the **emails** claim.

Answer (score 1):

No idea if this is still relevant to you, Azure AD B2C essentially uses standard OpenID Connect, however with the addition that you need to supply a policy as additional parameter.

We also had the need to use Azure AD B2C with oauth2_proxy, so we modified the oauth2_proxy generic oidc provider so it can take a B2C policy as additional config option.

If you want, give it a try: https://github.com/karrieretutor/oauth2_proxy#microsoft-azure-ad-b2c

If you're building from source, be aware that you also need to use our forked 'go-oidc' package (on which oauth2_proxy relies, but has part of the issuer URL hardcoded, so we had to change this, too, for including the B2C policy). Take a look at the Dockerfile, this can properly build it.